# TODOs in Java classes are not showing in TODO list

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ there is a TODO tab which shows a list of TODOs in my project.

Unfortunately it only shows TODOs in non java classes (eg. YAML files)

See screenshot.

Is there any way to fix this? I couldn't find any option in the settings.

[image]

There seems to be nothing wrong with the settings :

[image]

In another project it *does* seem to work. Here is an example where it does work. It is from the same IntelliJ instance but pointing at another GitHub project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug that we can't reproduce: https://i.imgur.com/HsFGVoz.png. What's your IntelliJ IDEA version? Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. Does it help?

Comment: no. problem is still there. I just have new problems now, like my tests not being able to run anymore.

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new. Attach a sample project to reproduce the issue and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Java files, you use a different pattern to identify TODO items. Add your pattern to "Settings | Editor | TODO"

Comment: no. that did not help. There is no pattern that is defined. I have updated my question with more info.